# Pebble.js app pulling in the wrong image resource

Tags: pebble-watch, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I am trying to create a simple app in *pebble.js* using the cloud IDE

I have my resources loaded (47 of them) with a colour and a black and white image, with all the correct naming conventions. Here is a snippet from the appinfo.json

```
{
    "file": "images/34_Unlockables.png",
    "name": "IMAGES_34_UNLOCKABLES_PNG",
    "type": "png"
},
{
    "file": "images/45_Leaderboards.png",
    "name": "IMAGES_45_LEADERBOARDS_PNG",
    "type": "png"
}
```

When I reference the image by it's name, the app pulls in the wrong image totally. This is the same if I try the url as well

```
card.banner('images/45_Leaderboards.png');
card.banner('IMAGES_45_LEADERBOARDS_PNG');
```

both result in the wrong image (and it is always black and white).

Has anyone else hit a similar issue?

Comment: Are you using a Pebble Time? I am not aware of PebbleJS having anything new added as part of the latest models and as such might not be allowing the images to be loaded in anything but grayscale. How much storage space do these images use up anyways? 

Have you tried removing the black and white images and leaving only the color images to see what happens? If it's still looking Black and White, you may want to try uninstalling the app from your device and then reinstalling it fresh to remove anything that might have been cached.

Comment: Hi. It is a pebble time. I think the colour issue may relate to the emulator as it happens. The more concerning issue is that it is pulling the wrong image totally. So if it is meant to get image "image1" it may pick up "image22"

Comment: Have you tried now on an actual pebble watch?

Comment: How are you adding the images? Cloudpebble file tool? I see now they have a B&W and Color file upload so you can have two versions of images. Are you seeing that?

Comment: @KennethSalomon yes, I have. Still getting the B&W image on the watch. I am looking to see if it is a pallet issue. The image is still coming from the wrong resource though. Also, I have used the tool and I have done direct editing on the resource json file. Both give me the wrong resource when I call it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a new project just as a test? Try setting a new project up and adding just a small amount of information, enough to get the image to load and see if that changes things.